# Pythonanywhere server does not receiving any updates from Telegram via webhook

Tags: python, telegram, webhooks, pythonanywhere

All was working until I updated repository. Nothing was change in this piece of code. But it happed not working now. The get_message function not even calls.

```
URL = 'name.pythonanywhere.com'
app = Flask(__name__)

bot.remove_webhook()
bot.set_webhook(url=URL)

bot.send_message(userID, 'helo')
context = context.Context(default.Default())

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_message():
    update = types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode('utf-8'))
    bot.process_new_updates([update])
    return 'ok', 199
```

Here is a result from getWebhookInfo method. The url property is correct.

```
{"ok":true,"result":
{"url":"name.pythonanywhere.com",
"has_custom_certificate":false,
"pending_update_count":11,
"last_error_date":1673875844,
"last_error_message":"Connection timed out",
"max_connections":40,
"ip_address":"35.173.69.207"}}
```

I checked certificate- it's ok. I tried to set webhook with ngrok URL, but i was failed.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue arose after the repository update, it seems likely that that caused the problem. Try reverting to see whether that fixes it. If it does, then the diff will be useful for debugging